# what is better? many AsyncTasks or one to handle all AsyncRequest?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

currently I have an app that creates all sorts of different requests to Facebook and my server, and I was wondering if the best way to do this is implementing a different `AsyncTask` or using the same `AsyncTask` for all the different requests.

what do you think?

---

Here is a use-case for instance:

I send a Facebook connect request, when I get to `onComplete`, I get the users Information with FQL (has to be Asynchronous) , when the response comes back, the user's image is posted on the main view.

After this, the app sends a different request to the app's background server and gets a response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you must decide it for yourself.
If you have lots of requests beware of the android's limitation of number of AsyncTasks. If you hit that limit your app will crash.
Also notice that if you assign many jobs to a single AsyncTask you could have a very long running task on the background.
You can also read this article -> [The Hidden Pitfalls of AsyncTask](http://logc.at/2011/11/08/the-hidden-pitfalls-of-asynctask/).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use concurrent `AsyncTasks` to ensure all the other requests are run in case one of them won't return an answer.